Sales data aggregation in R
I have daily sales data for multiple products in three stores. It looks something like this:



item_id
store_id
category_id
dept_id
date
event_name
daiy_price




a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/24

6


a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/25
christmas
6


a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/26

6


a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/27

7


a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/28

7


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/24

6


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/25
christmas
6


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/26

6


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/27

7


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/28

7



I want to round each week to the monday date using floor_date from lubridate package in R, then use group_by and summarise to compute weekly price average. However, i want each week to retain event_name if there is any during a particular week. Including event_name in group_by is not helpful since a day in a week may have an event but other days may not and they get grouped separately. Say each week starts on a monday and 2012/12/24 is a monday, how do i achieve this



item_id
store_id
category_id
dept_id
date
event_name
weekly_avg_price




a
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/24
christmas
6.4


b
tx_1
food
1
2012/12/24
christmas
6.4




You can achieve your desired output for this toy example by filling in the empty event names and then summarising the weekly prices by event_name and taking the first of the other columns.
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mutate(df, week_start=floor_date(date, unit = "week", week_start = 1)) |> 
  group_by(item_id, store_id, category_id, dept_id) |>
  fill(event_name, .direction="downup") |>
  ungroup() |>
  summarise(store_id=first(store_id),
            category_id=first(category_id),
            event_name=first(event_name), 
            dept_id=first(dept_id),
            weekly_avg_price=mean(daiy_price, na.rm=TRUE), .by=c(item_id, week_start))

Gives:
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  item_id week_start store_id category_id event_name dept_id weekly_avg_price
  <chr>   <date>     <chr>    <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>            <dbl>
1 a       2012-12-24 tx_1     food        christmas        1              6.4
2 b       2012-12-24 tx_1     food        christmas        1              6.4


Data:
df <- structure(list(item_id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b"), store_id = c("tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1", 
"tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1", "tx_1"), category_id = c("food", 
"food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", 
"food"), dept_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), date = structure(c(15698, 
15699, 15700, 15701, 15702, 15698, 15699, 15700, 15701, 15702
), class = "Date"), event_name = c(NA, "christmas", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "christmas", NA, NA, NA), daiy_price = c(6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 
6, 6, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

